# CSS style class of two menus which both have same route but different query parameters (v-navigation-drawer)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using **Vue** and **Vuetify** both **v3**.

For navigation I'm using `v-navigation-drawer` component and `v-list` for each menu as:

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-list nav>
      <v-list-item title="Threads" value="threads" to="/threads" link />
      <v-list-item title="My Threads" value="myThreads" to="/threads?by=lucien" link />
      <v-list-item title="Another Menu" value="anotherMenu" to="/another" link />
      ...
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>
```

Two first menus uses **same route** and they are different just in **query parameters**, so when I choose one of them, the other one is also get a background color (grey) of selected item.

[image]

What is the best solution to treat them as two separate menu while they have same route but different query parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom active in `v-list-item`:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

const router = useRouter()
const myThreadsActive = computed(() => router.currentRoute.value.fullPath === '/threads?by=lucien')
const threadsActive = computed(() => router.currentRoute.value.path === '/threads' && !myThreadsActive.value)
</script>

<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-list nav>
      <v-list-item title="Threads" value="threads" to="/threads" link :active="threadsActive" />
      <v-list-item title="My Threads" value="myThreads" to="/threads?by=lucien" link :active="myThreadsActive" />
      <v-list-item title="Another Menu" value="anotherMenu" to="/another" link />
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>
```